# Webfarm authentication

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, web-farm

Could someone help me with a problem of authentication asp. net webfarms?
I have two applications: an application .net framework 3.5 with another .net framework 4.5
both use the same authentication system asp.net and have the same machine key.

They are in the same domain, like this:

```
http://www.example.com/application1

http://www.example.com/application2
```

But when I make the sign in application1, authentication is not accepted by the other.
when I make the sign in application2, it overwrites the first authentication.

**UPDATE:**

The systems are using the default authentication of Microsoft .Net and are referenced in the server as follows:

```
www.cotoso.com/application1
www.cotoso.com/application2
```

They also share the same cookie: `aspauth`.

Comment: `dominio/application1` and `dominio/application1` doesn't have any domain. What's their domain (e.g. application1.dominio.com)?

Comment: Updated the question to correct the domain. I think now it's more clear. Can you understand it now?

Comment: We need more details about your authentication system, can you post some code? Do you share the code between the 2 applications?

Comment: Do you have the same problem on Local?

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that different .NET versions support different signign and authentication algorithms.
As far as i can tell by the information given (im guessing), you should try to use a self signed certificate and import it to both machines.
Also a good way to see what's happening and where requests are going you can check out Fiddler: http://www.telerik.com/fiddler